# How to solve redirection in Django auth is not working

Tags: python, django, authentication

Here is my code. Everything is working fine but when I tried to log in and hit on login button nothing happens. My login page didn't redirect me on any page. 
Login page code:

```
{% extends 'authenticate/base.html' %}
 {% block content%}
 <h1 class="text-center">Login </h1>
 <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3"
 <form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter UserName" 
 name="username">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" 
 name="password">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}`
```

Views.py page code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'authenticate/home.html',{})

def login_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)   
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
       return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

Base.py page code:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
 <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'login'%}">Login</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try to replace href="{%url 'login'%}"> with href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}

Comment: by 'nothing happens' do you mean the page is not sending the post request or the page is loading to the same login page after authentication?

Answer (score 1):

```
def login_user(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST) 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)   
            return redirect('home')

        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: hello mohit thanx for answering

Comment: should i remove these lines from my code                                                             
 else:
            return redirect('login')
    else:

Comment: after remove that lines i am getting unbound local error at /login/

Comment: try again ,fix indentation@RashidChaudhary

Comment: same error. now when i click on login button from my home page. i am getting unbound local error /login/

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment
this error

Comment: yes mohit i tried it. know login button on my home page is working but login form is not responding after click on login button on login form